# ViewController as Overlay on MapView in Swift (like Google Maps Application User Interface)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uicontainerview

I'm building a small app with Swift where I want to achieve following:
- MapView with several Annotations
- Click on one of the annotations shows some Details in an overlay that is moving in from the bottom and fill approx. half of the screen
- The upper half of the display still shows the MapView. A click on the map closes the details

Now I've read a lot about different possibilities. First I've tried using a ContainerView with something like this:

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailsContainerYPosition: NSLayoutConstraint!

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self. detailsContainerYPosition.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem with that was, that the viewDidLoad() method was only fired once and I wanted to use that to build up the Details page after passing some data to the controller class.

So next I've played around with a custom segue and cam up with this:

```
class DetailsSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        // Assign the source and destination views to local variables.
        var mapView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
        var detailsView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

        // Get the screen width and height.
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
        detailsView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth, 140)

        // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(detailsView, aboveSubview: mapView)

        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            detailsView.frame = CGRectOffset(detailsView.frame, 0.0, -140)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This seems to be the better solution because I could send some data to the new controller within the prepareForSegue() function AND the viewDidLoad() method is fired every time this segue is initiated but now I'm struggling:
- Everytime the annotation is clicked and the segue is called, a new View is inserted. But if ONE detail view is already visible, I would like to just update this one
- I can't find any way to unwind this segue when didDeselectAnnotationView is called from the MapView.

But perhaps anybody here has even a better way to achieve an UI like this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967555/how-can-i-mimic-the-bottom-sheet-from-the-maps-app/51768193?noredirect=1#comment94269686_51768193

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally managed to get what I wanted by manually adding a ViewController and a view like this:

```
let detailsWidth: CGFloat = view.bounds.width
let detailsHeight: CGFloat = 150
let detailsViewFrame: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height, detailsWidth, detailsHeight)

detailsController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("details") as! DetailsViewController
detailsController.descriptionText = "I'm a text that was passed from the MainViewController"

self.addChildViewController(detailsController)
detailsController.view.frame = detailsViewFrame
view.addSubview(detailsController.view)
detailsController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

And when dismissing the Details, I remove the Controller like this:

```
self.detailsController.removeFromParentViewController()
```

I created a small sample to demonstrate my solution:
https://github.com/flavordaaave/iOS-Container-View-Overlay

Comment: Thank you but it looks like that your GitHub project is empty ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I just updated the project so it now contains the actual code.