# iOS name of UI menu in Apple Maps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm wondering what's the name of the draggable menu at the bottom of the iOS map. (See picture :)

[image: Apple Maps bottom menu]

I want to implement the same kind of interface for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not called anything special, but some refer to it as "Card". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152508/5576310) is a great tutorial of how to implement the bottom card as Apple Maps, from the question:

[How can I mimic the bottom sheet from the Maps app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967555/how-can-i-mimic-the-bottom-sheet-from-the-maps-app)

Comment: Thank you a lot =)

Comment: In UI design, it's actually referred to as a sheet.

Comment: @AdamAllard, any reference for that statement? There is [Action Sheets](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/action-sheets/), but not just Sheets as I can see.

Comment: @RashwanL in UIKit, no. There isn't a system component for it yet - Although I can see them making one given its popularity. But for future, you may hear designers refer to it as a sheet. It's also referred to as a bottom sheet in Android: https://material.io/components/sheets-bottom/#behavior