# Apple Maps style menu popup

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I'd like to create a view similar to the maps settings menu and the apple pay menu. I tried to make a segue that came from the bottom but couldn't find how to make it smaller than the full screen.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mimic the bottom sheet from the Maps app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967555/how-can-i-mimic-the-bottom-sheet-from-the-maps-app)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating an xib file (just called "view") and setting the background to transparent. I then added the file to my ViewController and animated it from the bottom when I needed it (all from ViewController.swift)

This was linked to the button to show the menu in the main view controller's file

```
@IBAction func showSettings() {
    let settingsViewVC = SettingsMenuController()

    self.addChildViewController(settingsViewVC)
    self.view.addSubview(settingsViewVC.view)
    settingsViewVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    let height = view.frame.height
    let width  = view.frame.width
    settingsViewVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.maxY, width: width, height: height)

}
```

This was linked to a button that covers the top area of the screen to close the view when you tap off of it

```
@IBAction func exit() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { [weak self] in
        let frame = self?.view.frame
        self?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame!.maxY, width: frame!.width, height: frame!.height)
    })
}
```

I am sure there are better ways to do this with storyboards, but this works

Comment: Pretty close to my answer, just instead of view controller you used view. Glad you made something you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to produce something like this is following:

- Create `UIViewController` with desired components.
- Setup constraints as you wish
- Set `backgroundColor` as transparent ( or opacity if you wish darkened background on parent ) for topmost view in view controller
- Present view controller

This way you will be able to show your controls with visible parent view controller - depends on your opacitiy it could be 1-1 visiblity or little bit shadow over it. Also you will have full control over componenets so `cornerRadius` shown in the picture won't be problem.

I would add tap gesture as well on the topmost view so you can dismiss it that way.