# Change dragging one view to another in same gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to reproduce the buttom sheet in Apple's iOS 10 Maps app. Most of it is working. I've been looking at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967555/how-to-mimic-ios-10-maps-bottom-sheet) and [Pulley on GitHub](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley), but none of them solves my issue.

When the sheets is fully opened, it is possible to scroll the content of the sheet as a `UITableView`, but when the user tries to scroll down (where the `UITableView`'s `contentOffset` would be negative), the gesture is dragging in the sheet instead of the `UITableView`. The gesture seamlessly changes from dragging the `UITableView` to dragging the sheet.

It is possiple disable the scrolling of the `UITableView` in the gesture delegate's `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith`, but this is only called when a gesture begins.

I can't control the `panGestureRecognizer` of the `UITableView`, so I can't just capture the gesture and determine what view it should move.

**How can I change what `UIGestureRecognizer` should recognize touches, in the middle of a gesture?**

[image: screenshot of Apple's iOS 10 Maps app]

Comment: cant you implement shouldRecogniseGesture for your custom pan, and return tableView.contentOffset == 0

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer == myCustomPanGesture {
        return self.tableView.contentOffset == 0
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This causes both the tableview and the sheet to be scroll as the same this. While the sheet is being dragged down, is the `UITableView`s `contentOffset`'s growing. This also doesn't solve; if the gesture starts dragging at a positive `contentOffset`, the gesture wount change to dragging the sheet when the `contentOffset` reaches zero.

Comment: hmm it may be you have to create an invisible view with a pan on and designate where the translation goes.

Comment: But then I would loose the scrolling effect of the `UITableView` when you give it a swipe, and it's running free and it gradually decreases velocity. Right?

Comment: yeah essentially unless you recreated that yourself by saving pan velocity and overriding targetContentOffset and returning a value based on the velocity but it would never be the same i expect