# What is the name of the bottom sheet UIKit component used in Apple Maps?

Tags: ios, uikit

Can't find name of this view. It is a search controller that can be dragged from bottom to top. It's used in Apple Maps and Apple Music.

[image: screenshot of the view]

Comment: This is not UI component, this is clear button in UISearchBar

Comment: Please note that your image is misleading... You have highlighted the close button, but your question is about the "sheet" presented from the bottom (?)

Comment: You can create similar UI with UIView or you can also take seperate UIViewController. This 3rd party library will help you to create similar UI. https://github.com/52inc/Pulley

Comment: @Alladinian Sorry for that, I will change image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mimic the bottom sheet from the Maps app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967555/how-can-i-mimic-the-bottom-sheet-from-the-maps-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps uses a private UI component to achieve this draggable view, so **it's not available for third-party apps that are planned to be distributed through the App Store**.

As suggested by [@ivarun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776470/ivarun), you can check out **[Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley)** to achieve a similar result in your application. The library uses a custom `UIViewController` subclass named `PulleyViewController`, which hosts the drawer's content.