# How to reproduce iOS 11 maps bottom sheet with React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

Can anyone tell me how I can mimic the bottom sheet in the new maps app in iOS 11?

In android you can use a "BottomSheet", which mimics this behaviour, but I could not find anything like that for iOS.

Is that a simple scroll view with a content inset? So that the search bar is at the bottom?

I am fairly new to iOS programming so if someone could help me creating this layout that would be highly appreciated.

This is what I mean by "bottom sheet":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see this is old an question but for anyone struggling with this issue. you can use this module  https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable. Here is demo

https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable/blob/master/playground/src/real-life-examples/MapPanel.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give a try to Modalize https://github.com/jeremybarbet/react-native-modalize I've been working on it to be able to create all kind of bottom sheets similar to that.

Answer (score -1):

It´s not called anything special, but some refer to it as "Card". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152508/5576310) is a great tutorial of how to implement the bottom card as Apple Maps.

Comment: But how to implement in ReactNative?