# How to create an Action-Sheet/Bottom-Sheet style drawer in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated, react-navigation-drawer

I would like some guidance on how to create an action-sheet/bottom-sheet style drawer in React-Native so that I could use a single code base for both iOS and Android.

I've attempted to use the Animated Spring API. However, I'm not able to change to location of the Spring from the original location (while the drawer is closed), to the top location (while it is open). So that if the user doesn't complete the gesture, the menu goes back to its original location in either state, instead of the original position at the bottom.

Furthermore, many of the other answers to similar questions all recommend using their own or some other package on GitHub/NPM.

I'd like to make my own to keep dependencies small. I've also considered using React-Navigation but I can't seem to find anything that fits my use-case.

Comment: What is bottom sheet style drawer? An example would help.

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808157/how-to-reproduce-ios-11-maps-bottom-sheet-with-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react-native-action-sheet is great if you're looking to get as close as possible to the native versions of Action Sheets.

https://github.com/expo/react-native-action-sheet