# ChildViewController/View does not get focus with GMSMapView

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

**Context**: I want to achieve something similar with [How can I mimic the bottom sheet from the Maps app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967555/how-can-i-mimic-the-bottom-sheet-from-the-maps-app/38152508#38152508) based on https://github.com/grendio/XBottomSheet/tree/master/XBottomSheet.Samples/XBottomSheet.Touch

**Problem**: If I use the BottomSheet with Google Maps for iOS View it does not let me to drag up or down the BottomSheet, even if it adds (it's visible on the screen).

**Code**: As already mentioned I have a Google Maps View and my BottomSheet View:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        SetMap();
        SetBottomSheet();
    }

    private void SetMap()
    {
        var frame = new CGRect(0, View.Frame.GetMaxY(), View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);
        mapView = new MapView(View.Frame);
        mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true;

        mapView.BuildingsEnabled = false;
        mapView.SetMinMaxZoom(15f, 18f);

        View = mapView;
    }

    private void SetBottomSheet()
    {
        var bottom = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height - UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height;
        bottomSheetViewController = new BottomSheetViewController(100, 300, bottom, true, BottomSheetState.Middle);

        AddChildViewController(bottomSheetViewController);
        View.AddSubview(bottomSheetViewController.View);
        bottomSheetViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);

        bottomSheetViewController.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, View.Frame.GetMaxY(), View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);
    }
```

How can I wire these two views (mapView and bottomSheetViewController.View) in order to not lose the drag up/down feature from the BottomSheet control?

Even if the question is for Xamarin, an answer from swift or objective-c will do just fine as I will do the 'translation' afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar project, my solution at that time was to set the **ConsumeGesturesInView** property to **false**.

So your **SetMap()** method should look like this:

```
private void SetMap()
{
    var frame = new CGRect(0, View.Frame.GetMaxY(), View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);
    mapView = new MapView(View.Frame);
    mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true;
    mapView.Settings.ConsumeGesturesInView = false;
    mapView.BuildingsEnabled = false;
    mapView.SetMinMaxZoom(15f, 18f);

    View = mapView;
}
```