# How to create bottom sheet style model view controller using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to create `button` click to present bottom sheet `viewcontroller` using `storyboard` not code base. View controller swipe down to dismiss viewcontroller with background light dark effect.

I tried below `cocoapods` but I didn’t get easy way.

https://github.com/gordontucker/FittedSheets

Please, give me some ideas how to achieve this by using `Storyboard`?

[image: Bottom sheet sample image]

Comment: were you having trouble with the `cocoapod` or is it something else?

Comment: @DennisW. I am expecting without cocoapod. Could you please give me some idea...how to achieve this by storyboard..

Comment: I think `SO` is the wrong place for "How do I do make this" question. You should look for a tutorial such as [view controller presentation transitions](https://www.raywenderlich.com/359-ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions) or [similar tutorial](http://www.swiftkickmobile.com/building-better-app-animations-swift-uiviewpropertyanimator/)

Comment: @DennisW. both links are not helpful. Actually I am looking storyboard with two view controller.

Comment: Sorry they didn't help you, try searching for a tutorial on `UIPresentationController` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mimic the bottom sheet from the Maps app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967555/how-can-i-mimic-the-bottom-sheet-from-the-maps-app)

Answer (score 4):

Might be too late but I juste released a Framework that does exactly what you need.
https://github.com/Que20/UIDrawer

- It is a custom UIPresentationController, it doesn't affect you view controller presenting or the modal itself.
- It support swipping and dragging (to deploy and close).
- It is customizable.

Hope it'll help :)